# Django celery, celery-beat: fills the queue without control, scheduling troubles

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, celerybeat

I have small project with couple of tasks to run several times a day.
The project is based on Django 2.1, having celery 4.2.1 and django-celery-beat 1.3.0. And also have rabbitmq installed.

Each task is inside it's projects application. Runs, works, gives some result.
The problem is - on virtual server, leased from some provider, if I set any task to run periodically (each hour, or two)- it starts running immidiately, without end and, as i suppose in some kind of parallel threads, wish mesh each other.
Command `rabbintmqctl list_queues name messages_unacknowldged` always shows 8 in queue `celery`. Purging the queue `celery` does not give any changes. Restarting service - too.

But setting tasks schedule to run in exact time works good. Well,  almost good. Two tasks have schedule to run  in the beginning of different hours (even and odd). But both run in about 30 minutes after hour beginning, of the same (odd) hour. At least tasks don't run more times in a day than set in schedule. But it is still something wrong.

As a newbie with rabbitmq and celery don't know where to look for solution. Official celery docs didn't help me. May be was not looking in right place. Any help help or advice would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is bug of django-celery-beat - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4041.
If anyone have already made any solution for this - please inform.